consistency of "OFFSET" in PostgreSQL query
I am trying to make a script which changes a lot of db entries (>100Mio entries)
since this is so much, I need to work in some kind of batches. Now to find the correct batch I do something like this:
const BATCH_SIZE = 1000;
const PARALLEL_BATCHES = 10; // Adjust based on your CPU and DB capacity

export const updateAltitudeHeightInDB = async () => {
  try {
    // Get the total number of entries
    const totalEntriesResult = await lodsql
      .unsafe('SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM cj_geometry')
      .execute();
    const totalEntries = parseInt(totalEntriesResult[0].total, 10);

    // Initialize the progress bar
    const progressBar = new cliProgress.SingleBar({}, cliProgress.Presets.shades_classic);
    progressBar.start(totalEntries, 0);

    let offset = 0;
    let promises = [];
    while (offset < totalEntries) {
      if (promises.length >= PARALLEL_BATCHES) {
        await Promise.all(promises);
        promises = [];
      }

      // Fetch entries from the LOD database in parallel batches
      promises.push(
        (async () => {
          const entries = await lodsql
            .unsafe(
              `
                SELECT cj.*, m.scale, m.translate, m.epsg
                FROM cj_geometry cj
                JOIN metadata m ON cj.metadataid = m.metadataid
                LIMIT ${BATCH_SIZE} OFFSET ${offset}
              `
            )
            .execute();

          const updates = [];
          for (const entry of entries) {
          

              //make some voodoo with each entry

              
              // Store update queries for bulk execution
              updates.push([height, altitude, entry.id]);
            }
          }

          if (updates.length > 0) {
            // Execute bulk update
            await lodsql.unsafe(
              `
                UPDATE cj_geometry
                SET height = tmp.height, altitude = tmp.altitude
                FROM (VALUES ${updates.map((_, i) => `($${3 * i + 1}, $${3 * i + 2}, $${3 * i + 3})`).join(',')}) AS tmp(height, altitude, id)
                WHERE cj_geometry.id = tmp.id;
              `,
              updates.flat()
            ).execute();
          }

          progressBar.increment(BATCH_SIZE);
        })()
      );

      offset += BATCH_SIZE;
    }

    await Promise.all(promises);
    progressBar.stop();
  } catch (error) {

  }

};

updateAltitudeHeightInDB();

What I am wondering now is, how reliable the "OFFSET" parameter in the initial query is. Will it always return the correct batch? or is the search in millions of entries sometimes different?
Or is there an entirely different way to do this?
I need to use NodeJS because for the calculations of each entry there are some libraries necessary which I can only use in node.
Thanks a lot!
EDIT:
editing the Code according to answers here.
Does that make more sense?
   let lastId = 0
    let hasMoreEntries = true

    while (hasMoreEntries) {
      // Step 1: Fetch entries from the LOD database in batches based on last processed ID
      const entries = await lodsql
        .unsafe(
          `
        SELECT cj.*, m.scale, m.translate, m.epsg
        FROM cj_geometry cj
        JOIN metadata m ON cj.metadataid = m.metadataid
        WHERE cj.id > $1
        ORDER BY cj.id
            LIMIT ${BATCH_SIZE}
            `,
          [lastId]
        )
        .execute()
      // console.log('Entries to work on from: ', lastId)

      if (entries.length === 0) {
        hasMoreEntries = false
        break
      }

      const updates = []
      for (const entry of entries) {
      
          // DO THE MAGIC....
          // Collect update values for batch processing
          updates.push([height, altitude, entry.id])
        }
      }

      // Step 3: Perform bulk update with RETURNING to get the last processed ID
      if (updates.length > 0) {
        const updateQuery = `
          UPDATE cj_geometry
          SET height = tmp.height, altitude = tmp.altitude
          FROM (VALUES ${updates
            .map((_, i) => `($${3 * i + 1}::float, $${3 * i + 2}::float, $${3 * i + 3}::int)`)
            .join(',')})
          AS tmp(height, altitude, id)
          WHERE cj_geometry.id = tmp.id
          RETURNING cj_geometry.id;
        `
        const updatedRows = await lodsql.unsafe(updateQuery, updates.flat()).execute()
        // console.log('Updatedrows', updatedRows)

        // Update lastId to the highest ID processed
        lastId = Math.max(...updatedRows.map((row) => row.id))
        // console.log('Last ID: ', lastId)
      }

      progressBar.increment(updates.length)
    }


OFFSET is reliable. The query and the concept are wrong though. The query has no ORDER BY though so there's no guarantee what rows will be retrieved. There's no implied order, in any database, much less PostgreSQL which creates new rows on update. Without an ORDER BY any database is free to return rows in the cheapest way possible. Even after adding an ORDER BY though, performance will get progressively slower. Every execution has to find the rows to skip, so every batch will take longer than the previous one to retrieve

Does cj_geometry have an incrementing primary key? If it does, you could keep track of the last processed MAX ID and update the next N rows directly (ie with just LIMIT N), until no more changes are made. You can use the RETURNING clause to return the IDs of the modified rows.

The answers in Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1 show how to use UPDATE, LIMIT and RETURNING together. If you keep track of the IDs, the SELECT subquery only needs a WHERE ID>last_id LIMIT 1000 to retrieve the next 1000 rows

Hi there, there is no id field which is reliably incrementing. any other idea what i could do? maybe make a new temp row with incrementing numbers?

Doesn't cj_geometry have a primary key or at least a unique column? As long as you order by that column, you can retrieve the "next" batch.

id is unique, but does not necessarily start at 0 - nor is it necessarily incrementing by 1

That's still incrementing.

i have added an updated code example to the original question. does that make more sense now?

Batching the batches into parallel batches doesn't make much sense.

Are you executing all of these statements inside a transaction? You may want to add a table lock if you really need to process all rows in the table.
